# determine number of rows of an (M,N) array and (M,) array with same function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a loop:

```
for i in range(np.shape(data)[1]):
    item1 = data[i,0]
```

Now this works for data which has a shape (M,N) but when it is a single row, it is (M,) and I can not access the [1] index of the tuple which provides the shape (which would be "1" in other languages). What is the correct pythonic way to always determine the number of rows in the incoming array without using try/exceptions.

EDIT:

```
np.shape(data)
Out[21]: (17,)

In [24]: np.shape(data)[-1]
Out[24]: 17

----> 1 np.shape(data)[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

The point is that it is not populated with a value at all for arrays of row length 1. I want the row number determined if I don't know whether the incoming array is just one row or N rows.

Edit:

The quickest way to do this I've found is to use ellipses and just ask for the size of the array over the first column -- depending on the size, you can use a different index, i.e.

```
sh = data[...,0].size
for i in range(sh):
    item1 = data[i,0]
        if sh == 1:
            item1 = data[0]
        else:
            item1 = data[i,0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to iterate over either the first column of a 2D array or just the first element of a 1D array, correct?

Why not just make it a 2D array? (I'm also looping directly over the array.) E.g.

```
for item1 in np.atleast_2d(data)[:,0]:
    print item1
```

If you pass in `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`, you'll get `1, 4`.  If you pass in `[1,2,3]`, you'll get `1`.

Or, if you want it to produce a column "vector"  when you give it a 1D array, use `column_stack([data])` instead. (using the term vector loosely, as neither row or column vectors are vectors -- they're 2D):

```
for item1 in np.column_stack([data])[:,0]:
    print item1
```

In this case, the 2D output is identical, but if you pass in a 1D array, it will iterate over the full array.

---

In other words:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: data1d = np.arange(10)

In [3]: data1d
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [4]: data2d = np.arange(20).reshape(2,10)

In [5]: data2d
Out[5]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

In [6]: np.atleast_2d(data2d) # <-- No change!
Out[6]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

In [7]: np.atleast_2d(data1d) # <-- Makes it a "row vector"
Out[7]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

In [8]: np.column_stack([data2d]) # <-- No change (note the []!)
Out[8]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

In [9]: np.column_stack([data1d]) # <-- Makes it a column vector
Out[9]:
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

Also see `np.c_`. For example:

```
In [11]: np.c_[data1d]
Out[11]:
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])

In [12]: np.c_[data2d]
Out[12]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

Comment: I just want to iterate over the 1st column or a MxN matrix even if N = 1. I don't want to reshape the arrays.

Comment: @Griff - Reshaping is "free".  It doesn't make a copy, and unless you alter things in-place, it doesn't modify the original data. There's no reason not to iterate over a reshaped array. It's the usual idiom in numpy.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want the last index, you could use `[-1]`

```
for i in range(np.shape(data)[-1]):
    item1 = data[i,0] # if only rows exist, second index might throw an exception
```

- In case there are only rows, it will give you the rows
- In case there are rows and columns it will give you the columns
- Works for arbitrary depth

Comment: I want the number of rows only. I don't know whether the data array will have rows and columns or just columns from the outset -- hence my problem.

Answer (score 1):

A reshape like this might do the job

```
data1 = data.reshape(data.shape[0],-1)
```

A `(M,N)` array remains the same shape, a `(M,)` becomes `(M,1)`.

```
for i in range(data1.shape[1]):
    item1 = data1[i,0]
```

or how about

```
for row in data1[:N,0]:
   item1 = row
```

I'm wondering why you only want to iterate over a subset of the 'rows' `(range(data.shape[1])`.  In the `(M,)` case, do you want to use just one value, or all `M`?

If you want to iterate over the 1st column (i.e. M values)

```
for row in data1:
    item1 = row[0]
```

or

```
for item1 in data1[:,0]:
    pass
```

edit:
To use your ellipsis idea; you don't need to iterate at all if `sh==1`

```
sh=data[...,0].size
if sh==1:
    item1 = data[0]
else:
    for i in range(sh):
        item1 = data[i,0]
```

`sh` could also be used in full iteration

```
for row in data:
    # row is now either vector or scalar
    item1 = row if sh==1 else row[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.size(data)/np.shape(data)[0]` should work